# Why/how do private IP address show when emails are sent from webmail client such as Gmail/yahoo?

Tags: email, ip, private, public

I wanted to get some clarity on something that im a bit confused about at the moment.

If i send an email from my outlook, from a gmail account to any other account, the IP of the sender is the correct public IP address.

However, when i send an email from a webmail client such as Gmail.co.uk, the IP address of the sender is private. is this right and Why is this?

Also, my theory is that when emails are sent and received by the same provider such as example@gmail.com to example2@gmail.com, the IP's are again private as the email wont need to divert from gmail servers? Can someone prove me right/wrong on this.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Gmail hides the sender IP for privacy when emails are sent via their web app. [I believe the Gmail SMTP server includes the headers though](https://www.quora.com/Does-sending-email-from-Gmail-expose-your-IP-address-to-the-sender).

No, if the email is still sent via a mail client, there is no reason that the client IP address would be hidden between emails on the same provider.